# How to show that $\frac{((1+T)^{p^n-1}-1)}{((1+T)^{p^e-1}-1)}$ is a polynomial?

Tags: number-theory, polynomials

I am currently stuck at computing the polynomial (with $0<e<n$):
$$\frac{((1+T)^{p^n-1}-1)}{((1+T)^{p^e-1}-1)}$$
From the context I already know that it should be a distinguished polynomial, as that is used in a larger proof. By polynomial division I know, that if the quotient of two distinguished polynomial is a polynomial, then it is also distinguished, but I struggle at showing that in this case the quotient is a polynomial.

First of all I set X=1+T as this should be easier to compute and starting the polynomial division I got:
$$\frac{((X)^{p^n-1}-1)}{((X)^{p^e-1}-1)}=(X)^{p^n-p^e}+(X)^{p^n-2p^e+1}+(X)^{p^n-3p^e+2}+(X)^{p^n-2p^e+1}+(X)^{p^n-4p^e+3}+\dots$$
But I can´t see how this is going to be a polynom. Either I made a mistake at the polynomial division or I am overlooking something.
Thank you for helping me.